# Haskell pretty printing

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I want to print a tree in a "pretty" format. I am using [Text.PrettyPrint.GenericPretty](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.15/GenericPretty-1.2.1/Text-PrettyPrint-GenericPretty.html) and [Text.PrettyPrint](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/pretty-1.1.2.0/Text-PrettyPrint.html). My tree can be nested with pairs of ints, strings, identities.

My code so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import System.IO ( stdin, hGetContents )
import System.Environment ( getArgs, getProgName )
import System.Exit ( exitFailure, exitSuccess )

import LexNav
import ParNav
import SkelNav
import AbsNav

import System.Environment

import Language.LBNF.Compiletime
import qualified Language.LBNF.Runtime as L hiding (Ok, Bad)

import Text.PrettyPrint.GenericPretty
import Text.PrettyPrint

main = pp tree1


main = do 
    args  <- getArgs
    conts <- readFile (args !! 0)
    let tokens = myLexer conts
        pTree  = pProg tokens
        let tree = transProg pTree
    putStrLn (show tokens)
    putStrLn "----- \n\n ---- next -----"
    putStrLn (show (pp pTree))
```

I Found an example:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint.GenericPretty

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Generic)

instance (Out a) => Out (Tree a)

tree1 :: Tree Int
tree1 = Node (Node (Leaf 333333) (Leaf (-555555)))(Node (Node(Node(Leaf 888888) 
        (Leaf 57575757))(Leaf (-14141414)))(Leaf 7777777))

main = pp tree1
```

Works fine, but not with my tree. How can I get it working with my tree format? My tree looks like this:

> Ok (ProgBlock (Block1 (Declarations1 (DeclarationVar_declaration (Var_declaration1 (Ident "x") (Array_dimensions1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 2)))))) Array_dimensions2) Type_int)) (Declarations1 (DeclarationFun_declaration (Fun_declaration1 (Ident "exp") (Param_list1 (Parameters1 (Basic_declaration1 (Ident "b") Basic_array_dimensions2 Type_int) More_parameters2)) Type_int (Fun_block1 (Declarations1 (DeclarationVar_declaration (Var_declaration1 (Ident "z") Array_dimensions2 Type_int)) Declarations2) (Fun_body1 (Prog_stmts1 (Prog_stmt1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factor2 (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "b") (Modifier_listArray_dimensions Array_dimensions2)))) Compare_op1 (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 0)))))) (Prog_stmt4 (Identifier1 (Ident "z") Array_dimensions2) (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 1))))))) (Prog_stmt4 (Identifier1 (Ident "z") Array_dimensions2) (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_term1 (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "x") (Modifier_listArray_dimensions (Array_dimensions1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 1)))))) Array_dimensions2)))) Mulop1 (Int_factor6 (Ident "exp") (Modifier_list1 (Arguments1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_expr1 (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "b") (Modifier_listArray_dimensions Array_dimensions2)))) Addop2 (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 1)))))) More_arguments2)))))))))) Prog_stmts2) (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "z") (Modifier_listArray_dimensions Array_dimensions2))))))))))) Declarations2)) (Program_body1 (Prog_stmts1 (Prog_stmt3 (Identifier1 (Ident "x") (Array_dimensions1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 0)))))) Array_dimensions2))) (Prog_stmts1 (Prog_stmt3 (Identifier1 (Ident "x") (Array_dimensions1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 1)))))) Array_dimensions2))) (Prog_stmts1 (Prog_stmt5 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "exp") (Modifier_list1 (Arguments1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factor6 (Ident "x") (Modifier_listArray_dimensions (Array_dimensions1 (ExprBint_term (Bint_termBint_factor (Bint_factorInt_expr (Int_exprInt_term (Int_termInt_factor (Int_factorInteger 0)))))) Array_dimensions2)))))))) More_arguments2))))))))) Prog_stmts2))))))

I get the following

```
Error: 
> No instance for (Show (IO ())) arising from a use of ‘show’
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(show (pp pTree))’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (show (pp pTree))
    In the expression:
      do { args <- getArgs;
           conts <- readFile (args !! 0);
           let tokens = myLexer conts
               pTree = pProg tokens;
           putStrLn (show tokens);
           .... }

> TestNav.hs:33:21:
    No instance for (Out (ErrM.Err Prog)) arising from a use of ‘pp’
    In the first argument of ‘show’, namely ‘(pp pTree)’
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(show (pp pTree))’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn (show (pp pTree))
```

The tree is a parse tree of the following grammar:

prog -> block

block -> declarations program_body.

declarations -> declaration SEMICOLON declarations
             |.

declaration -> var_declaration
             | fun_declaration.

var_declaration -> VAR ID array_dimensions COLON type.

type -> INT
      | REAL
      | BOOL.

array_dimensions -> SLPAR expr SRPAR array_dimensions
             |.

fun_declaration -> FUN ID param_list COLON type
                                            CLPAR fun_block CRPAR.

fun_block -> declarations fun_body.

param_list -> LPAR parameters RPAR.

parameters -> basic_declaration more_parameters
            |.

more_parameters -> COMMA  basic_declaration more_parameters
            |.

basic_declaration -> ID basic_array_dimensions COLON type.

basic_array_dimensions -> SLPAR SRPAR basic_array_dimensions
             |.

program_body -> BEGIN prog_stmts END.

fun_body -> BEGIN prog_stmts RETURN expr SEMICOLON END.

prog_stmts -> prog_stmt SEMICOLON prog_stmts
            |.

prog_stmt -> IF expr THEN prog_stmt ELSE prog_stmt
           | WHILE expr DO prog_stmt
           | READ identifier
           | identifier ASSIGN expr
           | PRINT expr
           | CLPAR block CRPAR.

identifier -> ID array_dimensions.

expr ->  expr OR bint_term
       | bint_term.

bint_term -> bint_term AND bint_factor
           | bint_factor.

bint_factor -> NOT bint_factor
             | int_expr compare_op int_expr
             | int_expr.

compare_op -> EQUAL | LT | GT | LE |GE.

int_expr -> int_expr addop int_term
          | int_term.

addop -> ADD | SUB.

int_term -> int_term mulop int_factor
          | int_factor.

mulop -> MUL | DIV.

int_factor -> LPAR expr RPAR
            | SIZE LPAR ID basic_array_dimensions RPAR
            | FLOAT LPAR expr RPAR
            | FLOOR LPAR expr RPAR
            | CEIL LPAR expr RPAR
            | ID modifier_list
            | IVAL
            | RVAL
            | BVAL
            | SUB int_factor.

modifier_list -> LPAR arguments RPAR
           | array_dimensions.

arguments -> expr more_arguments
           |.

more_arguments -> COMMA expr more_arguments
           |.

Comment: What is your tree format, and what error do you get?

Comment: @sclv the tree at the bottom of the question, and I added the error there.

Comment: You've given me the concrete expression for the tree you're pretty printing. I want the declaration of the tree data type itself. I.e. the equivalent of `data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Generic)` for your tree type.

Comment: In any case, the error message suggest that you shouldn't call `putStrLn (show (pp pTree))` but instead just `pp pTree`...

Comment: @sclv thanks - the tree is a parse tree generated from the grammar. I have added the grammar as well. I tried pp pTree, didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? Was there an error message? What was it?

Comment: what error do you get with `pp pTree`? (you may find this advice on asking questions useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that whenever you say "didn't work" you need to describe the actual error.

Comment: Got this:   No instance for (Out (ErrM.Err Prog)) arising from a use of ‘pp’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: pp pTree
    In the expression:
      do { args <- getArgs;
           conts <- readFile (args !! 0);
           let tokens = myLexer conts
               pTree = pProg tokens;
           putStrLn (show tokens);
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { args <- getArgs;
                 conts <- readFile (args !! 0);
                 let tokens = ...
                     ....;
                 .... }

Comment: You need to provide an instance of `Out` for `ErrM.Err` (or handle the error) and an instance for `Prog`. Presumable `instance Out Prog` and `instance Out a => Out (ErrM.Err a)` would work if these types have `Generic` instances.

Answer (score 1):

This error tells you the problem:

```
No instance for (Out (ErrM.Err Prog))
```

So try:

```
instance (Out a) => Out (ErrM.Err a)
instance Out Prog
```

And if those types fail to have `Generic` defined for them, you need to write something like

```
deriving instance Generic Prog
```

and

```
deriving instance (Generic a) => Generic (ErrM.Err a)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just replacing '(' with \n\t\t? That will pretty print it. How do I approach this?